# Why i can not add a row in data.frame?

Tags: r

I  want to add a row in my data.frame:

```
x<-data.frame(sex=c("male","female"),number=c(2340,1890))
z<-data.frame(x,prop=x$number/sum(x$number))
z[3,]<-c("total",sum(z$number),sum(z[,3]))
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "total") :

z
     sex number              prop
1   male   2340 0.553191489361702
2 female   1890 0.446808510638298
3   <NA>   4230                 1

> z[3,1]<-"total"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "total") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

How can i change  `z[3,1]` into  "total"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the level to the factor first (followed by your line of code):

```
levels(z$sex) = c(levels(z$sex), "total")
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the column to be a factor:

```
z$sex = as.character(z$sex)
```